# Navigation stack's observation buffer & Costmap2DROS transform

Tags: ros, buffer, costmap-2d-ros, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What my errors are

```
 The base_scan observation buffer has not been updated for 1056.13 seconds, and it should be updated every 0.40 seconds.
 Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1310714584.1730, global_pose stamp: 1310714583.0928, tolerance: 0.3000
```

What am I missing? I have checked rxgraph to make sure all connections are set.

My launch file is

```
 <launch>
    <!-- Navigation Core -->
   <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false"      name="move_base_node" output="screen">
       <remap from="map" to="/map" />
       <param name="controller_frequency" value="10.0" />
       <rosparam file="$(find nav_core)/conf/costmap_common_params.yaml"      command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
       <rosparam file="$(find nav_core)/conf/costmap_common_params.yaml"      command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
       <rosparam file="$(find nav_core)/conf/local_costmap_params.yaml"      command="load" />
       <rosparam file="$(find nav_core)/conf/global_costmap_params.yaml"      command="load" />
       <rosparam file="$(find      nav_core)/conf/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
     </node>
   
   <node pkg="robot_setup_tf" type="tf_broadcaster"      name="transform_configuration_name" output="screen">
     <param name="transform_configuration_param" value="param_value" />
   </node>
 
   <node pkg="robot_setup_odometry" type="odometry" name="odom_node"      output="screen">
     <param name="odom_param" value="param_value" />
   </node>
 
   <node pkg="robot_setup_laser" type="laser" name="sensor_node_name"      output="screen">
     <param name="sensor_param" value="param_value" />
   </node>
 </launch>
```

view_frames Result

```
 /odom->/base_link->/map

        /base_link->/base_laser
```

costmap_common_params.yaml

```
 #This file contains common configuration options for the two costmaps used in      the navigation stack for more details on the parameters in this file, and a full list of the      parameters used by the costmaps, please see http://www.ros.org/wiki/costmap_2d
 
 #For this example we'll configure the costmap in voxel-grid mode
 map_type: voxel
 
 #Voxel grid specific parameters
 origin_z: 0.0
 z_resolution: 0.2
 z_voxels: 10
 unknown_threshold: 9
 mark_threshold: 0
 
 #Set the tolerance we're willing to have for tf transforms
 transform_tolerance: 0.3
 
 #Obstacle marking parameters
 obstacle_range: 2.5
 max_obstacle_height: 2.0
 raytrace_range: 3.0
 
 #The footprint of the robot and associated padding
 footprint: [[-0.325, -0.325], [-0.325, 0.325], [0.325, 0.325], [0.46, 0.0], [0.325,      -0.325]]
 footprint_padding: 0.01
 
 #Cost function parameters
 inflation_radius: 0.55
 cost_scaling_factor: 10.0
 
 #The cost at which a cell is considered an obstacle when a map is read from the      map_server
 lethal_cost_threshold: 100
 
 #Configuration for the sensors that the costmap will use to update a map
 observation_sources: base_scan
 base_scan: {data_type: LaserScan, expected_update_rate: 0.4,
   observation_persistence: 0.0, marking: true, clearing: true, max_obstacle_height: 0.4, min_obstacle_height: 0.08}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10607/navigation-stack%27s-observation-buffer-&-costmap2dros-transform/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-15**:
I have updated,thanks.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-15**:
Could you post your costmap_common_params file? And the output of 'rosrun tf view_frames' while you are seeing that error so we can verify that your frames are connected properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you~
I solved it.
In my global_costmap_params.yaml I set the static_map to false,
because I misunderstanding that parameter.
Before I think static_map means the map is static not generate by gmapping dynamically.
So I choose static_map parameter to be false,because I want to do a online slam.
When I change static_map to true,that two warning message disappeared!

---

Originally posted by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-18**:
Why when I only run :export ROBOT=sim and roslaunch navigation_stage move_base_gmapping_5cm.launch. It also showed that " The /base_scan/scan observation buffer has not been updated for 126.30 seconds" and couldn't move by setting goal on rviz. What happened?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-17**:
Sorry for my misunderstanding again. I found that when I change the setting, it just ask for a map first. That situation let me think my question is solved,but not. Because when I give it a static map to try,the same problem showed again...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your laser scan is not updated at the expected update rate you set. This may be because you forgot to set the topic name for the base_scan observation source.

See the [costmap_2d parameters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/costmap_2d#Sensor_management_parameters) for details. Make sure you fill in the "topic" parameter for the base_scan observation source.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-07-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-07-18**:
Have you verified with something like "rostopic hz base_scan" that your laser scan is actually being published? Are you able to visualize the scan in the map frame in rviz?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-17**:
That example means a really code or settings run on real robot. I have try to add `topics: "base_scan" sensor_frame: "sensor_msgs/LaserScan"` on costmap_common_params.yaml but not works.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-17**:
You mean like the Costmap Configuration section of the Navigation stacks's Robot Setup tutorial? http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup#Costmap_Configuration_.28local_costmap.29_.26_.28global_costmap.29

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-16**:
Thank you~Is there any example about this?